# Gradle Sync error occured. Help to Fix this

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, development-environment

Gradle sync error. Please help me to fix this. I Googled it and none of the solutions worked.

```
.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression
                    org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.TupleExpression cannot be cast to org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression
                    Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
                    Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
                    The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
                    Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
                    Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
                    In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
                    Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (5 m 2 s 700 ms)

02:15 PM    Gradle sync started

02:16 PM    Gradle sync failed: org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.TupleExpression cannot be cast to org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression
                    org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.TupleExpression cannot be cast to org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression
                    Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
                    Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
                    The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
                    Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
                    Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
                    In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
                    Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (3 s 62 ms)
```

Comment: Have you checked the logs?, also would you post both your build.gradle (project level) and the build.gradle (app/module level) files

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is with one of the libraries you use for this project, you should check each library alone to see where the problem is.